Requesting Notification permission token with Firebase Cloud Messaging
I'm trying to request a Notification permission token with Firebase Cloud Messaging with JavaScript. My current code works, but as explained in the code comment, there seems to be a strange behavior regarding the steps.
What should happen:

User clicks on send reminders html button,
browser asks for notifications permissions,
user clicks on allow,
user receives the current_token value.

What is actually happening:

User clicks on send reminders html button,
browser asks for notifications permissions,
user clicks on allow,
user doesn't receive the current_token value,
user has to click on send reminders html button again,
this time the user receives the current_token value (of course without the need of click on allow, because the permissions were previously granted).

To my best understanding, when messaging.getToken is executed, the code inside then(function(current_token) is only reached if the user has previously granted notifications permissions, but this should happen in one single action.
Here's my current code:
html
<button type="button" id="remind_me">send reminders</button>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.0.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.0.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>

javascript
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js', {
        scope: '/'
    }).then(function(registration) {
        console.log('fcm: service worker registered successfully');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('fcm: service worker registration failed:', error);
    });
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration) {
        console.log('fcm: service worker is ready');
        window.onload = function() {
            console.log('fcm: service worker is ready and page is fully loaded');
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                console.log('fcm: service worker active and controlling page');
                sw_ready();
            } else {
                console.log('fcm: service worker ready but not yet controlling page');
                registration.addEventListener('controllerchange', function () {
                    console.log('fcm: service worker active and controlling page');
                    sw_ready();
                });
            }
        };
    });
}

// default sw ready
let sw_ready = function () {
    $('#remind_me').click(function(e) {
        // request permission for firebase cloud messaging
        console.log('fcm: attemping to get token');
        messaging.getToken({
            vapidKey: config.firebase.messaging // this is a valid vapidKey
        }).then(function(current_token) {

            // THIS PART OF THE CODE IS ONLY REACHED
            // THE 2ND TIME #remind_me IS CLICKED ON
            
            // check token
            if (current_token) {
                console.log('fcm: token accquired', current_token);
            } else {
                // request denied
                console.log('fcm: user denied permission for notications');
            }

        }).catch(function(error) {
            // error while retrieving token
        });
    });
}

Any ideas? Thanks!

Try to remove sw_ready and onload event. Your $('#remind_me').click can be added as Soon as DOM is ready use $(function() { });. You don't need to wait for the service worker to add an event to the DOM.
